# Minimum requirements to run a full node?

Tags: iri-node

what are the minimum requirements to run a full node? Can I use my normal pc to run a full node or do I need an extra pc? Does the fullnode have to be up 24/7? And where can I find the best description to set up a full node with only little knowledge in coding?

Comment: In your question there are multiple issues. The one in the title was answered [here](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/31/212) so it could be a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, sorry. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this https://medium.com/deviota/iota-nelson-ready-for-public-preview-a958c6d0a531

Its better when the PC is running 24/7 and you need a minimum of 4gb Ram and about 10gb free disk space.

Good luck! :-)

Comment: 4 GB Ram is fine, 8GB is recommended however
10 GB of disk space may not be enough if the tangle keeps growing (there's a snapshot today so it should be fine for the time)

Answer (score 0):

- With regard to the last issue of your question you can find one of the best guide for setting up a full node on http://iota.partners/. The guide also says something about the minimum requirements for a full node (your main issue).
- It is highly recommended that a full node works 24/7, otherwise it will frequently be out of synch and that could harm the Tangle for various reasons one of which is well explained in the third point of [this](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/1396/212) answer.